# Find a string in a file and then find the first line above containing another string with bash

Tags: text-processing, string, search

How can I find a string in a file, then find the first instance of a line that contains 'srv' that precedes it.

I have been looking at Tac and sed, but have been unsuccessful at getting it to work right.

Output file to search looks like

```
srv-test-1 | SUCCESS | rc=0 >>
a1
A3
srv-test-2 | SUCCESS | rc=0 >>
a1
b1
b2
B3
B4
```

The code prompts the user for the string they are looking for and stores it to a variable.

I am able to find the users request using

```
tac file | grep $requested
```

if the user requests b1, I would like it to return

```
b1 found on srv-test-2
```

and likewise if requesting a1 it would return

```
a1 found on srv-test-1
a1 found on srv-test-2
```

Comment: `awk -v str=a1 '$0~str{print str" found on "srv}/^srv/{srv=$1}' file`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking to do the search for multiple items, you could convert the whole file into a grep'able list of entries.

```
awk '/^srv/ { c = $1 ; next } { print $0 " found on " c }'
```

on the input file would give you

```
a1 found on srv-test-1
A3 found on srv-test-1
a1 found on srv-test-2
b1 found on srv-test-2
b2 found on srv-test-2
B3 found on srv-test-2
B4 found on srv-test-2
```

Then to search for a single item, you could filter the previous output

```
awk '/^srv/ { c = $1 ; next } { print $0 " found on " c }' | grep '^a1'
```

to give

```
a1 found on srv-test-1
a1 found on srv-test-2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ requested='a1'; awk '$2=="|" { s=$1 }; $1==r { print r" found on "s }' r="$requested" file
a1 found on srv-test-1
a1 found on srv-test-2
```

The first part `$2=="|" { s=$1 }` assigns the content of the first field (`srv-test-XX`) to variable `s` if the second field is `|`.

The second part `$1==r { print r" found on "s }` compares the first field to variable `r` which holds the requested value.  If it matches, we print the result.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using `sed` editor as shown:

```
str='a1';          #string to search
str_esc_lhs=$(printf '%s\n' "$str" | sed -e 's:[][\/.^$*]:\\&:g');# escaped var fit for use on the lhs 
S='[^[:blank:]]'; #regex for a nonwhitespace char

$ sed -e "
   /srv/,/${str_esc_lhs}/!d
   H;/srv/h;/${str_esc_lhs}/!d
   g;/./!d
   s/\\(srv-$S*\\).*\\n\\(.*\\)/\\2 FOUND ON \\1/
" input_file.txt
```